# How to parse CSVs with newline and commas inside a field in Perl?

Tags: perl, csv

I'm new to Perl. This is a sample csv entry similar to mine. 
I would like to parse this, tried briefly Text::CSV, but no luck. The issue here is newline and 
commas inside fields. How could I parse this file in Perl? Thanks for the help.

```
1,A,"Length of x, where x is y"
2,B,"Set A to “10”, an invalid state"
3,C,"Solve
A+B and
B+A
"
4,D, Set C to B
```

Comment: Show the code you tried. It can probably be made to work Text::CSV is a good module

Comment: The best clue is ... don't try to parse CSV by yourself. Why do you think that `Text::CSV` did not work?

Comment: Sorry about that the post, I figured out the solution. I have posted it. 
Initially I was trying to parse myself, but later looked into Text::CSV but the issue was due to the option that I didn't include.
Sorry and Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code (taken directly from Text::CSV documentation):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;


my $rows;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                 or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $fh, "<", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";

while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
     push @{$rows}, $row;
}

$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();

close $fh;

# This gets rid of spaces at start and end of string 
# as well as newlines within the fields.
for ( 0 .. scalar @{$rows}-1 ) {
    $rows->[$_][2] =~ s/^\s*//;
    $rows->[$_][2] =~ s/\n/ /gms;
}

print Dumper($rows);
```

Produces the following output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '1',
            'A',
            'Length of x, where x is y'
          ],
          [
            '2',
            'B',
            'Set A to “10”, an invalid state'
          ],
          [
            '3',
            'C',
            'Solve A+B and B+A '
          ],
          [
            '4',
            'D',
            'Set C to B'
          ]
        ];
```

Which (I'm guessing) is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. This even takes care of the new line that gets printed in mine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure. Glad to be of assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Everyone who commented, I figured it out. The thing I didn't do was

```
{ binary => 1, eol => $/ }
```

Here is the working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

open(my $Fh, "<", 'datalane_csr.csv');

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ({ binary => 1, eol => $/ });
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($Fh)) {
  say @$row[2];
  }

close(CSV);
```

Thanks once again. And sorry for the post.

But I have a small issue, the '"' is shown as wierd characters when I print them.