# Parsing a csv file with \n between data

Tags: javascript, csv

Tried parsing a CSV file with new line in between the data because of which it is considered as a new row.

### Logic

```js
$scope.rows= file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
```

### Example

> "one" ,"two\nthree","four"

### Results

#### Actual

```
one
two
three
four
```

#### Expected

```
one
twothree
four
```

Comment: Did you mix-up your expected with your actual? Do you want to preserve the new line, or treat that value as two rows? What is an example of your input?

Comment: Please include an example of actual input or verify that is your actual input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse CSV data that contains newlines in field using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288375/how-to-parse-csv-data-that-contains-newlines-in-field-using-javascript)

Comment: I recommend using a library i.e. [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) for parsing CSV client-side. There is no need to re-write something that already works and has been thoroughly tested. You can quickly throw a [CDN link](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/PapaParse) into your document.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
$scope.rows= file.split(/,/);
```

See where it says "split(/,/);" we're saying split by the character quoted. i.e. a comma.

You have a \n in there, so it'll split by that in your example.

Comment: How do you know that's their actual input?